# Why isn't JQuery showing my autocomplete fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Context: I'm attempting to setup JQuery autocomplete using data that gets sent in from the server.  When a user changes a certain field, autofill data gets sent in from the backend such that they can select a supplied value if they so desire.  The backend code is perfectly functional, as I can see the array of autocomplete data if I `console.log(data)`it on the frontend.

My issue is that, even though the frontend code is effectively requesting and receiving the autocomplete data, when I used JQuery's built in autocomplete options, it never shows the options on the frontend.

Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url:"/autocomplete/"+event.target.id+"/"+$(this).val(),
      success : function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $(event.target.id).autocomplete({
          source: data
        });
      }
});
```

Where the `event.target.id` is the id of the input field that I'd like to autocomplete.  Again, all of this works perfectly fine.  When I `console.log(data)`, it shows the array of items I want to use for autocomplete, but when I actually run

```
$(event.target.id).autocomplete({source:data});
```

It doesn't show any autocomplete options on the frontend.

Any idea as to how I can fix this?  I've disabled my adblocker and tried it in a bunch of different browsers and the results never show as a standard dropdown-list autocomplete.

Comment: which browser - internet exploder has a global `event` object, which is the current event - chrome copied this absurdity ... your current `event` in `success` may not be what you think it is - console.log(event) before the ajax call, then again in the success callback - does it change?

Comment: I've found the solution using what you've given me.  When I console.log(event.target.id) it gives me the name of the field I want to autocomplete, but it doesn't give the "#" that's necessary to denote an id in JQuery.  I've posted the solution as an answer to my own question.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: d'oh, of course!! you just need `$(event.target)` instead - I'd still be careful when using a var called event, unless you cater for internet exploder stupidity :p

Comment: Nah, the solution wasn't using `$(event.target)`, as that returns a whole array of stuff.  The solution was using `$("#" + event.target.id)`, which works perfectly.

Comment: seriously, `$(event.target)` should be identical to `$("#" + event.target.id)` ... it's like `$(HTMLelement)` vs `$('#' + HTMLelement.id)` where HTMLelement has an ID attribute

Comment: Your solution works too, I just tested it.  If you post it as an answer to this question I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the tactics that [@Jaromanda X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x) suggested, I found that the `event.target.id` field was returning the name of the field I intended to autocomplete, but that it didn't include the "#" necessary to denote an id via JQuery.  The functional code looks like this now:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url:"/autocomplete/"+event.target.id+"/"+$(this).val(),
      success : function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $("#"+event.target.id).autocomplete({
          source: data
        });
      }
});
```

Yeah, it feels a little hacky, but code that runs is, in fact, code that runs.